# Java фрагментация кучи OutOfMemory

Tags: java, память, утечка-памяти, outofmemoryerror

Есть подозрение, что в приложении происходит фрагментация кучи. JVM запускается с параметрами -Xms1g -Xmx2g. Примерно через 12 часов куча занимает почти все пространство и GC перестает очищать эту память (как показывает VisualVM). Если верно предположение, что проблема во фрагментации кучи, как можно ее решить?

Comment: Какая нагрузка примерно? И какой сборщик мусора используете? Вот, посмотрите статью https://dzone.com/articles/choosing-the-right-gc. Может поможет вам понять что у вас и как работает. Может к вам прилетает что-то огромное. Поставьте опцию снимать дамп при `outofmemory` и потом проанализируйте его чем-то наподобии `Memory Analyzer (MAT) - Eclipse`

Comment: Куча дефрагментируется автоматически. Скорее всего мемори лик. Соберите дамп и проанализируйте что в нем.

Comment: @Chubatiy, нагрузка в среднем 15 документов в секунду. Бывает больше, когда сбрасывают сразу много документов. Количество записей в базу иногда 500 в секунду. Вот это вырвиглазный сайт по ссылке

Comment: На данном сайте просто есть диаграммы, которые показывают принципы работы того или иного GC. Возможно вам поможет выбор верного GC. Но опять же, если там memory leak, как сказали выше, то без анализа дампа памяти и потоков вы ничего не найдете.

Comment: понятно, что фрагментация тут не причем, любой  GC устраняет фрагментацию походя. У вас банальная утечка памяти: вы держите ссылки на уже ненужные объекты, и GC не может их утилизировать. Обычно такие ссылки находятся в static переменных.

Comment: Фрагментации в JVM нет, там дефрагментатор работает, да и фрагментация кучи за пределами VM выглядит не так, фрагментация это когда места совокупного много, а для нового объекта нет достаточного непрерывного адресного пространства, т.е. по цифрам свободного пространства все хорошо, а памяти не хватает. Так что там у вас утечка,  самые распространенные случаи утечек связанны с неправильным использованием HashMap, HashSet и ThreadLocal.